# C# copy paste lines from richtext1 to richtext2

Tags: c#, winforms, copy, paste, richtext

**RICHTEXT1 - Copy this selected lines types [0],[2],[4]  to clipboard:**

Type 1

Description of product 1

Type 2

Description of product 2

Type 3

Description of product 3

**RICHTEXT2- Paste lines with types [0],[2],[4]  to Richtext2 with selected "Types 1, 2, 3":**

New product 1

New product 2

New product 3

New product 4

New product 5

New product 6

My code:  works but deletes all richtext 2, Thanks for Help.

```
            string[] line = Clipboard.GetText().Split('\n');   // richtext1 copy lines to clipboard
            //string[] line = richTextBox1.Lines;
            //string line1 = richTextBox2.Text;
            string line1 = richTextBox2.SelectedText;

            richTextBox2.Text = line1.Replace("\n", "\n\n").Insert(0, "\n"); // Add new empty line in richtext 
            string[] line2 = richTextBox2.Lines;


            RichTextBox richText = new RichTextBox();

            for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
            {
                int x = i;

                if ((x % 2) == 0)  // define odd line
                {
                    //string l1 = line[i];
                    
                    richText.Text += "\n" + line[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    richText.Text += "\n" + line2[i];
                }
                richTextBox2.Text = richText.Text;
            }
```

**- After insert on Richtext2: (not afecting products 4,5,6)**

Type1

New product 1

Type2

New product 2

Type3

New product 3

New product 4

New product 5

New product 6

Answer (score 1):

In your implementation `richTextBox2` is reset per iteration.

```
var line = Clipboard.GetText().Split('\n'); 
var selectedText = richTextBox2.SelectedText;
var selectionStart = richTextBox2.SelectionStart;

var textBuilder = new StringBuilder(selectedText);
textBuilder.AppendLine();

for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
{
    int x = i;

    if ((x % 2) == 0)
    {    
        textBuilder.AppendLine(line[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        textBuilder.AppendLine(line2[i]);
    }
}

richTextBox2.Text = richTextBox2.Text.Substring(0, selectionStart) 
    + textBuilder.ToString() 
    + richTextBox2.Text.Substring(selectionStart + selectedText.Length);

richTextBox2.SelectionStart = selectionStart + textBuilder.Length;
```

This should do it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks AVTUNEY, you lead me to the solution :-). Great Help !!

```
        string[] line = Clipboard.GetText().Split('\n');   // richtext1 copy lines to clipboard to be copied

        string line1 = richTextBox2.SelectedText;         // Select richtext2 where we going to copy
        int textStart = richTextBox2.SelectionStart;      // define the start of the selection text
        int textLenght = richTextBox2.SelectionLength;    // define de lenght of selected text

        string beforeSelection = richTextBox2.Text.Substring(0, textStart);       // before the selected text
        string afterSelection = richTextBox2.Text.Substring(textStart + textLenght);    // after selected text


        richTextBox2.Text = line1.Replace("\n", "\n\n").Insert(0, "\n"); // Add new empty line in richtext + insert line on top
        string[] line2 = richTextBox2.Lines;
                    
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  // create new string

        for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
        {
            int x = i;

            if ((x % 2) == 0)  // define odd line
            {
                sb.Append(line[i] + "\n");    // if type them append
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(line2[i] + "\n");   // append the same text
            }
        }
        richTextBox2.Text = beforeSelection + sb + afterSelection;  // join all toghether :-)
```